# how can I get the uuid module for python 2.4.3

Tags: python

I have an older version of python on the server i'm using and cannot upgrade it. is there a way to get the uuid module?

Answer (score 5):

Get it from [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/uuid/) -- just download and install, it will work with Python 2.3 or better.

**Edit**: to install, first unpack the `.tar.gz` you just downloaded, i.e., from a terminal, cd to the directory you downloaded it to, then `tar xzvf uuid-1.30.tar.gz`, then `cd uuid-1.30`, and `sudo python setup.py install` (the `sudo` may or may not be needed depending on how your Linux system is set up; if it is needed, it will probably ask you for your password unless you've done another `sudo` very recently).

Comment: Ryan, if you want to know how to install it, update your question to ask that.  The way it's phrased now it seems you are just asking where to get it from.

Answer (score 1):

To continue where Alex left off..

- Download the uuid-1.30.tar.gz  from Alex's pypi link.
- unzip and untar.
- place the uuid.py to your application's python path (e.g., same dir with your own .py files)